# How to save the UID of a user on registering the user using firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, uid

I'm trying to save the UID of a user on registering the user using Firebase Auth.

Here I have already pushed the user UID as the key in the database under that I need to insert the same UID as a data

```
package com.example.loginregistration;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.rengwuxian.materialedittext.MaterialEditText;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class AddEmployee extends AppCompatActivity implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    MaterialEditText Username, email, password, mobile, dob, job, department;
    RadioButton radio_male,radio_female,radio_admin,radio_user;
    ImageView date;
    Button register;
    TextView LoginBtn;
    FirebaseAuth fAuth;
    FirebaseUser FirebaseUser;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Employee Employee;
    String currentDateString;
    long maxid=0;
    String user,id;
    Spinner spinner;
    String txtGender = "",txtUserName="", txtRole="";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_employee);


        Username = findViewById(R.id.username);
        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        //dob = findViewById(R.id.dob);
        job = findViewById(R.id.jobtitle);
        department = findViewById(R.id.department);
        mobile = findViewById(R.id.mobile);

        radio_male = findViewById(R.id.male);
        radio_female = findViewById(R.id.female);
        radio_admin = findViewById(R.id.Admin);
        radio_user = findViewById(R.id.User);

        register = findViewById(R.id.register);
        spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        //LoginBtn = findViewById(R.id.createText);
        Employee= new Employee();

        date = findViewById(R.id.date);
        date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                DialogFragment datePicker = new DatePickerFragment();
                datePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "date picker");
            }
        });

        fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Employee");

        reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              // if (dataSnapshot.exists())
                   // user = (dataSnapshot.getKey());
                //Log.e("User", user);
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



        /*if (fAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AppStartActivity.class));
            finish();
        }*/

        register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String txtUserName = Username.getText().toString();
                String txtEmail = email.getText().toString().trim();
                String txtPassword = password.getText().toString().trim();
                String txtMobile = mobile.getText().toString();
                String txtJob = job.getText().toString().trim();
                String txtDepatment = department.getText().toString();
              //String txtDob = dob.getText().toString().trim();
                String job = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().trim();

                String id = reff.push().getKey();
                Log.e("id",id);


                if(radio_male.isChecked()){
                    txtGender="Male";
                }

                if(radio_female.isChecked()){
                    txtGender="Female";
                }

                if(radio_admin.isChecked()){
                    txtRole="1";
                }

                if(radio_user.isChecked()){
                    txtRole="0";
                }


                //reff.child(String.valueOf(maxid+1)).setValue(Employee);
               // reff.child(txtUserName).setValue(Employee);

                Toast.makeText(AddEmployee.this,"Data inserted successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtEmail)){
                    email.setError("Email is Required.");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(txtPassword)){
                    password.setError("Password is Required.");
                    return;

                }

                if (password.length() < 6){

                    password.setError("Password must be more than 6 characters.");
                    return;

                }

                fAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtEmail,txtPassword).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){

                            FirebaseUser = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            user = FirebaseUser.getUid();
                            //Log.e("id", user);
                            reff.child(user).setValue(Employee);



                            Toast.makeText(AddEmployee.this,"User Created.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AppStartActivity.class));
                        }

                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(AddEmployee.this,"Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });


                //id = user;
                //Log.e("id",id);

                Employee.setEmail(txtEmail);
                Employee.setPassword(txtPassword);
                Employee.setUsername(txtUserName);
                Employee.setMobile(txtMobile);
                Employee.setJob(job);
                Employee.setDepatment(txtDepatment);
                Employee.setDob(currentDateString);
                Employee.setGender(txtGender);
                Employee.setRole(txtRole);
                Employee.setId(id);


            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth){
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        currentDateString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT).format(c.getTime());

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dob);

        textView.setText(currentDateString);


    }
}
```

And here is my database structure.[image]

Here I want to save the UID in the database which I couldn't get out of the concrete method of the firebase.

Im able to get the UID but not able to save the data, if I give save data in function inside the oncreate its not getting saved. outside the oncreate im numable to save the UID alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the UID of User. You are using the Database ID instead.

Please replace the line:

```
Employee.setId(id)
```

With this:

```
Employee.setId(userUID);
```

Here `userUID` will be fAuth.getCureentUser().getUID();
Also you need to turn few of your variable to final as you will be using it in another class. Android Studio will let you know about that.

Now it upload User UID :-)

To do that, first move your Employee setters in `task.isSuccessful()` and then it should work perfectly.

Comment: This will get the current who is logged in as Admin, but I want to add the UID of the user whom the admin is trying to add using the application.

Comment: @divyasekaran please step-by-step explain the procedure you are trying to achieve. .. IN your database structures are those Admin UIDs as parent node?

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve is that I have an admin account, from that I'm adding an employee and storing the employee details in the database. I'm able to store all other details except the UID which I'm using it as the key in the database.

Comment: So you want that UID starting from `9RR` in your screenshot inside the node also?

Comment: Yes exactly, that's what I'm trying to do

Comment: Then try updating the USER value in `Employee.setId(user)` ?? Because that is how you are uploading the parent node value. It should work . . use the `user` variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213062/discussion-between-divya-sekaran-and-dharmaraj).